# AuthorizeAttribute redirect in ASP.NET Core MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

What does a function level `[Authorize]` attribute do when an unauthorized user attempts to access the function?  Does the attribute attempt a log-in page redirect?  Is that information found somewhere?  My VS2015 project gets lost in space when the `[Authorize]` attribute is added.

Comment: Are you writing you custom [Authorize] attribute ?

Comment: No, this is straight out of the box newbee question.

Comment: We need more information. What sort of Authorization are you using? Post your Startup.cs code? What do you mean 'lost in space'? Does anything get returned to the browser (e.g. a 401)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please search in SO before asking a new question. For example, [site:stackoverflow.com Authorize mvc](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Authorize+mvc)

Comment: @mds Is it just showing a blank white page when you try to use the attribute?

Comment: It is just a blank white page.  A lot of code to post for something that is probably configuration glitch as indicated below.  I will mark Lukasz as answer and post more info if I find anything that might be relevant to SO.  Everyone has been incredibly helpful.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the attribute attempt a log-in page redirect?

Assuming of course, that we speak about login via *Individual User Accounts* (read @WillRay comments below):

If unauthenticated user try access to page/action decorated witch `[Authorise]` attribute then is redirected to login page, and after login is redirected back.

This is how it's work in my case at MVC Core WebApp.

> Is that information found somewhere?

You can find more information here:

- [ASP.NET Core Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html)
- [AuthorizeAttribute](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/simple.html)

> My VS2015 project gets lost in space when the [Authorize] is added

This works fine for me - both on RC1 and RC2.

Looks like somewhere you have wrong configuration.

Check if you have all required packages and clean up your `web.config`.

Or try new/clean project from VS template and check if it's works.

Comment: That was my bad on the edit - I moved it back into the brackets.

Comment: if you need more detailed answer, then give me your code example (controller, startup.cs, project.json) or better link to repo.

Comment: Not seeing anything, other than your comment, that talks about redirect routing for an unauthenticated user.  It searches for a file called "Login"?  Thank you.

Comment: It's out-of-box behaviour, if unauthenticated user lunch any actions with [Authorize] then will be automatically redirected to Login page (but it's action, not file) and after authenticate will be redirected back to action (page) where was before.

Comment: The Authorize attribute does not actually decide what happens when a user is not authorized. @mds is getting a white page because it is properly returning a 401 Not Authorized message, but there is nothing in the application telling it what to next.

Comment: @Will, I'm not telling that Authorize attribute decide about something. I'm telling about MVC Core WebApp behaviour - in my case, if unauthenticated user try access to page/action decorated witch [Authorise] then is redirected to login page, and after login is redirected back. I'm not sure where this logic is implemented, but this is how it's works.

Comment: @LukaszMakowej Your answer gives the impression that the Authorize attribute will always redirect to a login page, which it does not. One simple example is Windows Authentication (one of the default options when creating a project), which will not redirect at all.

Comment: @WillRay, yes, you have right - I assume that we speak about login via Individual User Accounts, because author mention about 'log-in page' - I will clarify my answer

Comment: @WillRay, Thanks for tip :)

Comment: @LukaszMakowej no problem! We're in this together. :]

Comment: The redirect is working now, but I have no idea why.  The first time user  attempts to get a listing  of trips and hits this code:                    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Trips()
    {
        return View();
    } Then the code is redirected to constructor                                public AuthController(SignInManager<WorldUser> signInManager).  Is that logic within the Authorize attribute?  What is the boilerplate code for redirecting when authorization fails?  Thank You.

Comment: After the AuthControlle constructor is called the execution jumps to public IActionResult Login().  That is all great, but does not seem to be in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you click on some kind of authentication when creating your Core project. I'm guess that you have a "No Authentication" template and put on Authorize attributes on it.

The white page you're seeing is probably due to the application correctly identifying that you are not logged in / authorized, but doesn't have anything else configured as to what happens next.

[image: VS authentication options]

> What does a function level [Authorize] attribute do when an unauthorized user attempts to access the function?

In .Net Core, it will validate a user based off of the policies that it has been given. It will return a failure if they do not meet them.

> Does the attribute attempt a log-in page redirect?

The Authorize attribute itself doesn't decide what happens when an unauthorized user attempts to access a method.